# Razor label dot period

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using mvc5 in combination with razor and fill website text dynamically based on language. example:

```
@Html.Label(@DDHelper.GetContent("user_name"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
```

`@DDHelper.GetContent("user_name")` returns a string, which is set as a label text. when `@DDHelper.GetContent("user_name")` returns "Hello." the label is not created and the html source is empty.

I know this is because `@HTML.Label()` does not allow '.' and that's the root of my problem and that I should use `@HTML.LabelFor()` but how can i use `@HTML.LabelFor()` when i just want to display a string?

Comment: try with quotes(').. like   '@DDHelper.GetContent("user_name")'

Comment: How about using a simple `Div`? - `<div class="control-label col-md-3">@DDHelper.GetContent("user_name")</div>`. If you want you can apply some other styles if you want.

Comment: nice alternative @ramiramilu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the overloads for @Html.Label, the one you're using is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper html, 
                                  string expression, 
                                  object htmlAttributes)
```

the one you want is

```
public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper html, 
                                  string expression, 
                                  string labelText, 
                                  object htmlAttributes)
```

There's a common misunderstanding of what an HTML `label` is.  On winforms, a label is where you put some text - this is not the case in HTML.  In HTML a `<label>` is to allow the user to click on your text and have the focus/cursor point to the corresponding input.

The full syntax for a label is:

```
<label for="controlName">caption</label>
```

The 'expression' part in the overloads above is the "for" part in the html - it must point to a control name.

If this is what you are trying to do (pair a label with a control) then try:

```
@Html.Label("user_name", 
            @DDHelper.GetContent("user_name"), 
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
```

Where your input is named 'user_name'.  This is where `@Html.LabelFor` comes in, something like:

```
@Html.Labelfor(model=>model.UserName, 
               @DDHelper.GetContent("user_name"), 
               htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
```

so you don't hard-code field names and they refactor.

If you "just want to display a string" then you probably don't want a `<label>`.  If you just need some simple text, you don't need an @Html anything and can just output the translation:

```
<div class='control-label col-md-3'>
    @DDHelper.GetContent("user_name")
</div>
```

but as you're using 'control-label' I suspect you do want `<label>`.

Comment: Thanks, I cant imagine i overlooked it!

Answer (score 0):

If Html.Label(..) is not an option I'd suggest an alternative:

```
<h4>@Html.Encode(@DDHelper.GetContent("user_name"))</h4>
```

Worked fine for me.